# htacess rewrite not redirecting original url to seo friendly

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have rewriteen htacess rules to create seo friendly urls.

i sucessfully changed my url from    `/abc.php?lType=x` to `/abc/x/`

but when i open `/abc.php?lType=x` it still works..i want to redirect it to `/abc/x/`
 to avoid duplicate pages.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On 

RewriteRule ^abc.php?lType=([a-zA-Z0-9]+) /abc/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^abc/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ abc.php?lType=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Help will be appreciated.

Thanks

**EDIT** am working on localhost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't match against the query string in a rewrite rule, so your pattern, `^abc.php?lType=([a-zA-Z0-9]+)` will always fail. The `?` is a regex reserved character meaning one or none of the preceding character. In this case, you'd want to match against `%{THE_REQUEST}` instead.

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+abc.php\?lType=([a-zA-Z0-9]+)
RewriteRule ^ /abc/%1? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: but its not redirecting me from orignal url to seo friendly `abc.php?lType=x` to `abc/x`

Comment: @Gopal it works [exactly the way you want it to for me](http://i.stack.imgur.com/mQLJN.png).

Comment: for me when i open `http://localhost/test/abc/` it shows not found error and `http://localhost/test/abc.php?lType=1` not redirecting ..do i need to add something in php file ?

Comment: @Gopal that's because you have `/test/` in your URL, you never mentioned that in your question, and it's not going to work unless you account for it by adding a `/test` in front of all the `abc.php`'s

Comment: sorry,i didn't thought directory `test` will be so important..Thanks much

Answer (score 0):

Will this help? :)

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^abc/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ abc.php?lType=$1 [L,QSA]
```

I think the first Rewrite Rule is not needed... And this is the mistake. I didn't check my answer and write it from hand, so it must be checked :).
Best regards!

Comment: sorry,i missed out something ...updated the question